# Woo Commerce Display New Price fields in Product Category Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hey gang I recently created new price fields for the woocommerce section of my site. The new fields are rrp and cost price. The fields I created work fine and display on the individual product page however they don't display on the product categories page. The old prices currently display on the categories (these need to be replaced by the new price fields)

Below is the script I created to add the new fields

```
 // RRP
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_rrp_product_field' );
function wc_rrp_product_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => 'rrp_price', 'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 'label' => __( 'RRP', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')' ) );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wc_rrp_save_product' );
function wc_rrp_save_product( $product_id ) {
    // If this is a auto save do nothing, we only save when update button is clicked
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['rrp_price'] ) ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $_POST['rrp_price'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'rrp_price', $_POST['rrp_price'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_rrp_show', 5 );
function wc_rrp_show() {
    global $product;
    // Do not show this on variable products
    if ( $product->product_type <> 'variable' ) {
        $rrp = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rrp_price', true );
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">';
        _e( 'RRP: ', 'woocommerce' );
        echo '<span class="woocommerce-rrp-price">' . woocommerce_price( $rrp ) . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

//New Price
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing','custom_cost_price');
function custom_cost_price() {
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => '_cost_price', 'class' => 'wc_input_price short', 'label' => __( 'Cost Price', 'woocommerce' ) .    ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')', 'type' => 'number', 'custom_attributes' => array(
                    'step'  => 'any',
                    'min'   => '0'
                ) ) );
}

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'save_custom_cost_price');
function save_custom_cost_price($post_id) {
    global $wpdb, $woocommerce, $woocommerce_errors;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cost_price', stripslashes( $_POST['_cost_price'] ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_cost_show', 5 );
function custom_cost_show() {
    global $product;
    // Do not show this on variable products
    if ( $product->product_type <> 'variable' ) {
        $rrp = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_cost_price', true );
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_msrp">';
        _e( 'Custom Price: ', 'woocommerce' );
        echo '<span class="woocommerce-cost-price">' . woocommerce_price( $rrp ) . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

My goal is to display the new product prices instead of the old product prices in the categories page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the custom price, you can display the new price in the front end with a code like this, fpor example, to show prices just to logge in users:

```
 if(is_user_logged_in()){

        return get_post_meta (get_the_ID(),'_cost_price',true);

 } else {

        return get_post_meta (get_the_ID(),'_regular_price',true);
 }
```

Anyway, to me, that kind of code works with any conditional, but, and that is a big but, the Cart does not take the price in the store I´m working with, and shows prices of $0.00 for all products.

Here's the code I use to display a custom price in the store:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'my_custom_price',99);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','my_custom_price',99);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_custom_price',99);


function my_custom_price( $original_price ) {

    global $post, $woocommerce;

    if (is_user_logged_in() && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),wp_get_current_user()->display_name,TRUE) == get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'admin',TRUE)){/*COnditional to check if the user is logged in and if a checkbox with his/her name is selected.*/ 

        return get_post_meta (get_the_ID(),'_cost_price',true);  //Get the custom price and return it to the filter. 

     } else {

        return get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true); //get regular price and return it to the filter
 }
```

}

All the code goes in functions.php file and the new price displays in category pages, shop and single product pages programatically according to the conditional.

I hope this help, at least partially.